# MySQL to SQL Server Migration Assistant has disappeared?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I read here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/3d3e7bb5-c7e4-4070-9f7f-953463306101 there is such an assistant but the link seems to have vanished from MS Site. Can I find it somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=69739c8c-ac82-41de-b9e6-8fa5ae2594d9